# What is the implicit subject of this -ing participle clause?

Tags: grammar

> A local repository is fast only if you have fast access to the data. A repository on NFS is often slower than the repository over SSH on the same server, allowing Git to run off local disks on each system.

Scott Chacon and Ben Straub, *Pro Git* (New York: Apress, 2014), chap. 4, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2.

In the second sentence of the quotation above, what is the implicit subject of the *-ing* participle clause? Is it "A repository on NFS"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I translated the sentence with google translate into Persian just in case and judging by the translation, yes, the implicit subject is "A repository on NFS"

If that wasn't the case, I believe the second part of the sentence should have read as follows:

which allows .....